# Show counts in Venneuler R package

Tags: r, numbers, label, venn-diagram

Does anybody know how to display the count of each subset in a Venneuler plot?
Also, how can I write the labels next to the circles instead of the default setting (inside the circles)?
Thanks very much!!

Here's an example from the package manual:

```
vd <- venneuler(c(A=0.3, B=0.3, C=1.1, "A&B"=0.1, "A&C"=0.2, "B&C"=0.1 ,"A&B&C"=0.1))
plot(vd)
```

Comment: Add your code. Make it [***reproducible***](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1478381).

Comment: Here's an example from the package manual:

vd <- venneuler(c(A=0.3, B=0.3, C=1.1, "A&B"=0.1, "A&C"=0.2, "B&C"=0.1 ,"A&B&C"=0.1))
plot(vd)

Comment: Great! I added it to your question to make it more visible to other viewing this

Answer (score 2):

This will show labels for counts manually added up:

```
vd <- venneuler(c(A=0.3, B=0.3, C=1.1, "A&B"=0.1, "A&C"=0.2, "B&C"=0.1 ,"A&B&C"=0.1))

vd$labels<- c(
  paste("A\n",0.3+0.1+0.2+0.1),
  paste("B\n",0.3+0.1+0.1+0.1),
  paste("C\n",1.1+0.2+0.1+0.1)
)

plot(vd)
```

[image]